# Is there a signficance to shuttle name SW-0608?

Tags: star-wars, names, rogue-one, behind-the-scenes

In the film *Rogue One: A Star Wars Story*, there is a cargo shuttle with an Imperial ID of SW-0608. Is there any out of universe significance to this designation?

For instance, one would assume "SW" = 'Star Wars', and the numbers appear to be a date, such as June 2008 (or August 2006 for other forms of date time stamp).

Comment: The first six Star Wars movies came out in May (1977, 1980, 1983, 1999, 2002, 2005), and the last two were both December (2015 and 2016). The eighth was initially accounted for May 2017, then pushed back to December 2017. Not a lot of sixes or eights anywhere in there.

Comment: It's also not George Lucas' birthday (May 14), Director Gareth Edwards' birthday (June 1), nor the release date of Lucas' early films like THX-1138.

Comment: There are six pre-Disney Star Wars movies, and eight including the Disney ones. That's all I can think of.

Comment: West Avenue 4, Sector 6, Level 8 perhaps.

Comment: @Broklynite - what is the significance of the address(?) you listed?

Comment: @NKCampbell obscure joke. It was the name of one of the Masters (Master 468 for short) from the 80's Tripods BBC series (based on the trilogy by John Christopher). It just looked vaguely similar enough to tickle a memory, but wasn't meant as a serious answer by any means.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[According to *Talk Star Wars*](https://www.talkstarwars.co.uk/news/the-meaning-of-sw0608-in-rogue-one), SW does not stand for *Star Wars*, but rather, Sebastian Weitz, the son of Chris Weitz, screenwriter of *Rogue One*. 06/08 is Sebastian's birthday.

> [image: screenshot]
>
> ...Sebastian Wietz[sic] is the son of the screenwriter of Rogue One (Chris Weitz). 06/08 is Sebastian's birthday.

Comment: That link is 1) dead and b) irrelevant. Also, the book is irrelevant for the question. This isn#t a forum, its a Q&A platform. furthermore, can you back up your claims or are they your own speculation?

Comment: The initials are correct for the Son, not sure about the birthday. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_Weitz